# Check element by element of two revered lists in python

Tags: python

How to check two lists which one is reversed other, and extract minimum value at each position, for example:

```
list1 = [3,4,5,2,1,7,4,1]
list2 = [1,4,7,1,2,5,4,3]

Output  = [1,4,5,1,1,5,4,1]
```

and here is my code:

```
min(list1, list2)
```

but it's wrong.

Comment: As you said, you have to do this element by element.  If you're new to Python, iterate through them with a **for** loop.  There's a one-line solution using a conditional list comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## With a *mapping*

You need to perform a *mapping* over the lists with `min` as function, for instance with:

```
>>> list(map(min, list1, list2))
[1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1]
```

## With *list comprehension* and `zip`

or an equivalent approach using `zip` and *list comprehension*:

```
>>> [min(t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]
[1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1]
```

## With numpy

For huge lists, we can boost performance by using numpy and process the arrays. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.min((list1, list2), axis=0)
array([1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1])
```

In case the result has to be a vanilla list again, we can pass the result back into a list:

```
>>> list(np.min((list1, list2), axis=0))
[1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4, 1]
```

Comment: When doing list comprehension, min can take an iterable (a tuple, for example), so there's no need to unpack x and y: `[min(i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]` is also an option

Comment: in python2.7 there is no need to use list(), since map return list

Comment: @Matt.St: yes, but here we do not know what version of Python we use. Furthermore within two years support for Python-2.x will stop. https://pythonclock.org/